# What happens when I run "php artisan ui vue --auth" in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 7 for the first time and don't have a good understanding of what exactly happens when I run "php artisan ui vue --auth".

I understand that Laravel 7 now has a separate UI Package that must be installed using "composer require laravel/ui:^2.4".

I don't really understand the interplay between these commands:

"php artisan ui vue --auth"
"php artisan ui vue"
"php artisan ui bootstrap"

If I want to use bootstrap, I assume I need to run "php artisan ui bootstrap"?  What actually happens when I run this?  Does it simply add bootstrap to my package.json and download the necessary files after I run npm install?  What happens when I run "php artisan ui vue"?

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the option to install bootstrap and adds some components of vue's templates to your UI.
Laravel gives you 3 options for bootstrap templates:

1. php artisan ui bootstrap
2. php artisan ui vue
3. php artisan ui react